# JPA - Not Saving Parent Table Id in Database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to insert `postId` in resource table while creating `POST` and `RESOURCE`. But unfortunately every-time I am getting `postId`->**null** in resource table. Below are hibernate mapping details.

**Post.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POST")
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public class Post  implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST}, orphanRemoval = true,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<>();
    //...Getters Setters
}
```

**Resource.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RESOURCE")
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public class Resource  implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="post_id",nullable=false)
    private Post post;
    ...
    //Getters Setters
}
```

**PostController.java**

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/posts")
    public class PostController {

    @Autowired
    private PostService postService;
    @Autowired
    private ResourceService resourceService;

        @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<PostDto> createPost(@Valid @RequestBody Post post) {
        Optional<User> userObj = userService.getOne(post.getUser().getId());
        //Check whether that user exist and resource null or not.
        if (userObj == null || post.getResources().isEmpty())
                return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
            post.setUser(userObj.get());

            // ----Issue HERE----> TRYING TO SET post id in RESOURCE TABLE.. WHICH IS NOT HAPPENNIG PREVIOUSLY

            Iterable<Resource> res = post.getResources();
            int id = post.getId();

            for(Resource r : res) {
                r.setPostFlag("1");
                r.setResourceFlag("1");;
            }
            // -----> Here Post and Resources are saved in database
            // But in resource-table post_id is null
            post = this.postService.savePost(post);
            if (post != null) {
                PostDto postDto = modelMapper.map(post, PostDto.class);
                return ResponseEntity.ok().body(postDto);
            }
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
}
```

**PostService.java**

```
    @Service
    public class PostService {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    // save Post
    public Post savePost(Post post) {
        return (Post) this.postRepository.save(post);
    }
}
```

**PostRepository.java**

```
    public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post,Integer> { ... }
```

The JSON object which I am passing to controller is:

```
    {
        "location":"NewEnry",
        "description":"NoDes",
        "state":"Active",
        "like":1234,
        "user": {"id":4},
        "resources":[{
            "url":"URL2",
            "state":"B1",
            "likes":200,
            "type":"My Type 1"
            },{
            "url":"URL3",
            "state":"B2",
            "likes":100,
            "type":"My Type 2"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Can anyone let me know what am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the code where you actually attempt to insert the data. Without that it's difficult to identify the problem.

Comment: @Domin0 I have added code of both tables

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a bidirectional `@OneToMany` mapping, it's the child-side `@ManyToOne` association that's in charge populating the post_id column with the identifier of the associated Post entity.
When the JSON is parsed into the Post, the Post reference on the child-side is null. Assigning the reference before the `postRepository.save()` should fix the problem:

```
for (Resource resource : post.getResources()) {
    resource.setPost(post);
}
```